# Why jquery not working in some case in visualforce

Tags: jquery, visualforce

Hi all i have a jquery simple alert which is working fine in my browser at my machine but strangely when i am at some other machine it simple even not giving me a alert(''); so can you help.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
'<script>
var previousOnload = window.onload;
window.onload = function (){
    if(previousOnLoad) previousOnload();
}
$.ajax();       
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() { 
alert('');
```

});
'

Comment: hi found answer to it i have to use https: insted of http: thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all Insted of using Http u can use Https and it will work..